# Cutting and joining multiple video segments in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, android

I'm trying to do this in as few steps as possible since I'm doing this in Android and FFMPEG SegFaults if run multiple times (in the same process).

Assume I have a 25 minute video: I want to cut from minute 1 to minute 5. I also want to cut from minute 8 to minute 13. I also want to cut from minute 17 to 23. I then want to stitch them together into a new video file.

I can do the above steps as their own individual steps (using `-ss` and `-t` as well as the `concat` filter); however, I'm wondering if it's possible to do this in FFMPEG in a single execution?

Comment: See [How to concatenate clips from the same video with `ffmpeg`](http://video.stackexchange.com/a/10401/1760).